# Include title of section when cross-referencing

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

How do I reference a section so that the output is the section title? I am writing in `bookdown` but a more general `rmarkdown` solution would be great.

For example:

```
# The best section {#thebest}
Read this many times.

# Some other section
Read [DON'T WANT TO WRITE THE TITLE HERE AGAIN](#thebest).
```

I would like some code to make the final line output this:

```
Read "The best section".
```

Comment: I use dashes between my words if the title calls for spaces (#the-best-section), HTH